# How do I split or join 2d array printed list with word 'is'?

Tags: python, arrays, split

I have tried append, 'is'.join, .split('is'), .replace, sep='' and my results look like this.

0is0is0is0is    is5is0is.is0is

is0is0is0is1is   is6is7is.is5is

array.txt file

0000 50.0

0001 67.5

0002 76.5

Expected Result

0000 is 50.0

What I have so far.

````
fo = open("array.txt")

line = fo.read()

for line in fo:

 line = line.split()

 line = [[0 for i in range (cols)] for j in range(rows)]

for row in line:

 print (line)

 break```
````

Comment: can you please format your question properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open the file, remove the `\n` from each line using `.rstrip()`, split the space using `.split(maxsplit=1)`, and join the two parts together using `" is ".join(...)`:

```
with open("arrary.txt") as data:
   for line in data:
     print(" is ".join(line.rstrip().split(maxsplit=1)))
```